Japan multiple entry visa for Indian citizen on F1 visa in the US
I want to apply for a 5 year multiple-entry visa to Japan while currently on an F-1 visa in the US. Does anyone know what the chances of me receiving a multiple entry visa are, given that I am on an F1 visa that expires in a couple of years? I have sufficient financial resources and I have been to Japan once before in 2023.

Which kind of visa? From your question, it seems you need it for your academic studies, right? So possibly you may have some supporting documents from local university. -- else: I do not think F1 change things. You may need to apply several time before getting multiple entry (like we do for India and most of world without strong reasons you didn't specify)

No, it is just a normal visit visa to Japan as outlined here: https://www.mofa.go.jp/files/100694646.pdf
